# Finger and Pencil width on PKCanvasView Different

Tags: swiftui, uiviewrepresentable, pencilkit, apple-pencil

I am trying to build out an application with the ability to use both apple pencil and finger input to draw. However, when I set the width of the tool to a sufficiently small number (1) the pencil input displays correctly, but when I use my finger it draws thicker lines. I would like uniformity in width when switching between pencil and finger. Any help would be appreciated. Bellow is the minimal reproducible code.

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI
import PencilKit

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        CanvasRepresentable()
    }
}

struct CanvasRepresentable: UIViewRepresentable {

    class Coordinator: NSObject, PKCanvasViewDelegate {
        var parent: CanvasRepresentable
        init(_ parent: CanvasRepresentable) {
            self.parent = parent

        }

        func canvasViewDrawingDidChange(_ canvasView: PKCanvasView) {
        }

    }


    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {

        return Coordinator(self)

    }

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> PKCanvasView {
        let c = PKCanvasView()
        c.isOpaque = false
        c.allowsFingerDrawing = true
        c.delegate = context.coordinator
        c.tool = PKInkingTool(.pen, color: .black, width: 1)
        return c

    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: PKCanvasView, context: Context) {
        let tool = uiView.tool as! PKInkingTool
        print(tool.width)
    }

}
```